# Capturing addresses of various types

Tags: r, regex

Got a df of addresses of which I want specific parts

```
address                  desired output               
960 Buford Highway       960         
14 Julie Way             14      
PO Box 1111              PO Box 1111
PO Drawer G              PO Drawer G
```

My current attempt is getting the first 2 correct but is only returning 'PO' for the last 2.

```
df = df %>% mutate(desired_output = stringr::str_extract(df$address, regex("(^\\S{1,15}\\s|^PO\\s(Box|Drawer\\s\\S{1,15})", ignore_case = T)))
```

Comment: Change your regex to ^PO\\s(?:Box|Drawer)\\s\\S{1,15}|^\\S{1,15}\\s                                         As you put this ^\\S{1,15}\\s in 1st position so it was matching first nonspace character (960, 14,PO) and didnt test with 2nd term(^PO\\s..)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option with `base R` where we capture 0 or more characters that are not a number (`[^0-9]*`) followed by one or more digits (`[0-9]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string, followed by the rest of the characters that are not a digit, in the replacement specify the backreference of the captured group (`\\1`)

```
df$desired <- sub("^([^0-9]*[0-9]+)[^0-9]*", "\\1", df$address)
df$desired
#[1] "960"         "14"          "PO Box 1111" "PO Drawer G"
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(address = c("960 Buford Highway", "14 Julie Way", 
"PO Box 1111", "PO Drawer G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gsub` to extract numbers at the begining of the string.

`\\d` matches a number from 0 to 9.

```
df %<>% mutate(desired_output = gsub("^(\\d+).+", "\\1", address))
df

#             address desired_output
#1 960 Buford Highway            960
#2       14 Julie Way             14
#3        PO Box 1111    PO Box 1111
#4        PO Drawer G    PO Drawer G
```